# Multi dimensional array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have values in my **attendance table** as follows 
[image]

sl_no is Foreign key reference register_table(`sl_no`)
        register_table Contains details about students like student_name etc...
        **My question is**,
        How can i get Attendance report in Table Format (Like Excel) Using Multi dimentional Array

**UPDATE**

I'm Querying the database as below, but am getting the results of same students in multiple rows, wherever they present it will create NEW ROW, I'm expecting to display in table format with different dates header for the same student name by using 2 dimensional array.

```
$sql="SELECT att.present,att.AttDate,r.student_name,r.university,r.batch FROM register_table as r inner join attendance as att on r.sl_no=att.sl_no WHERE university LIKE '$sdluniversity'";
     $result=mysqli_query($link, $sql);
     while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
          echo "<tr>";
          echo "<td>".$row['student_name']."</td>";
          echo "<td>".$row['present']."</td>";
          echo "<td>".$row['AttDate']."</td>";
          echo "<td>".$row['university']."</td>";
          echo "<td>".$row['batch']."</td>";
          echo "</tr>";
     }
```

Please Suggest me what are all the changes I need to make in the above code or my code is totally wrong to achieve my requirement.

I would like the output to look like this :

```
         Date1    Date1   Date3    University   Batch Average
Student1 present  present present Myuniversity  2012  100%
Student2 present  Absent  Absent  Myuniversity  2013  33%
Student3 present  present present Myuniversity  2012  100%
```

Like Excel Attendance Report, As I'm New webie Any help may greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use inner join on tables as

```
$sql='select att.present,r.university,r.name,r.rollNo from register as r inner join  attendance as att on r.sl_no=att.sl_no';
$sql = mysqli_query($con, $query);
$attendence = array();

while ($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)){

 if (!array_key_exists($data['userId'], $attendence))
    $attendence[$data['userId']]['student'] = $data['userId'];

$attendence[$data['userId']][$data['date']] = $data['present'];

}

echo "<pre>";
var_dump($attendence);
```

iterate each index of `$attendence` array to form a table having index as userId,dates you can also calculate average of their attendance

Comment: @Machavity I have updated how output to look like can you please tell me how to achieve output in that format

Comment: @Sha This isn't my answer

Comment: @Machavity I'm Expecting answer in that format by using your code I'm not able to display in that form please update your code.

Comment: I'm not getting any result From above code, I have `sl_no,student_name, university, batch in register table` and `schedulename,university,scheduleStartDate,scheduleEndDate in schedule table` can you please update exact column names with your code.